# elasticsearch autocompletion mapping using nest

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, autocomplete, nest

I am using nest to implement elasticsearch in .net and am new to it. I am trying to map suggesters please help me with it. how to do that in c# using nest

```
curl -X PUT localhost:9200/songs/song/_mapping -d '{
    "song" : {
        "properties" : {
            "name" : { "type" : "string" },
            "suggest" : { "type" : "completion",
                "index_analyzer" : "simple",
                "search_analyzer" : "simple",
                "payloads" : true
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: what is the problem? what is not working?

Comment: how to do this in c# using nest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the complete code below. It creates a new `ElasticClient` object and then adds the mapping `song` to the index `songs`. Make sure that index `songs` already exists before you execute this code. You can also create the index `songs` before creating the mapping through code anyways. I'll leave that upto you to figure out. Find an exhaustive example of how mappings can be created in Nest [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/develop/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Unit/Core/Map/FluentMappingFullExampleTests.cs).

```
var client = new ElasticClient(new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200")));

var response = client.Map<object>(d => d
    .Index("songs")
    .Type("song")
    .Properties(props => props
        .String(s => s
            .Name("name"))
        .Completion(c => c
            .Name("suggest")
            .IndexAnalyzer("simple")
            .SearchAnalyzer("simple")
            .Payloads())));

Debug.Assert(response.IsValid);
```

Comment: @bittusarkar can you help me to solve this [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37960029/how-to-add-completion-analyzer-on-an-attachment-fields-elastic-search-nest) please

Comment: No property called Type on PutMappingDescriptor